# same query and different result sql/plus php

Tags: php, oracle, sqlplus

I use oracle 11g and I don't know why my query return different result when I use SQL/PLUS and when I use PHP

```
<?php
$conn=oci_connect('system','3636','orcl'); 

$stid = oci_parse($conn,
"SELECT num_chb
 FROM chambre
 WHERE num_chb NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT r.num_chb
     FROM chambre c,
          reservation r
     WHERE (TO_DATE('2015-12-13','YYYY-MM-DD') NOT BETWEEN r.dat_arriv AND r.dat_depart)
       AND (TO_DATE('2015-12-14','YYYY-MM-DD') NOT BETWEEN r.dat_arriv AND r.dat_depart)");


oci_execute($stid);
$tab=array();

while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
   $tab[]=$row['NUM_CHB'];
}
print_r($tab);
}
?>
```

SQL PLUS AND PHP RESULT

[image: SQL PLUS AND PHP RESULT]

Comment: Are you sure that both examples (PHP & SqlPlus) are connecting on the same database?

Comment: Why did you specify MySQL and sql-server tags for an Oracle/SQL*PLUS question?

Comment: Your password for the `system` account is `3636`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing different queries:

PHP:

```
SELECT num_chb
 FROM chambre
 WHERE num_chb NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT r.num_chb
     FROM chambre c,
          reservation r
     WHERE (TO_DATE('2015-12-13','YYYY-MM-DD') NOT BETWEEN r.dat_arriv AND r.dat_depart)
       AND (TO_DATE('2015-12-14','YYYY-MM-DD') NOT BETWEEN r.dat_arriv AND r.dat_depart)
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT num_chb
 FROM chambre
 WHERE num_chb NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT r.num_chb
     FROM chambre c,
          reservation r
     WHERE (TO_DATE('2015-12-13','YYYY-MM-DD') NOT BETWEEN r.dat_arriv AND r.dat_depart)
       AND (TO_DATE('2015-12-14','YYYY-MM-DD') NOT BETWEEN r.dat_arriv AND r.dat_depart)
     AND (r.dat_arriv TO_DATE('2015-12-13','YYYY-MM-DD') NOT BETWEEN AND TO_DATE('2015-12-14','YYYY-MM-DD'))
       AND (r.dat_depart NOT BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-12-14','YYYY-MM-DD') TO_DATE('2015-12-14','YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

PD:I cannot comment.

Check again!